# PowerShell DNS Change script

Tags: powershell, dns

Im playing around with a DNS change script and I need help making it work for one interface. I am trying to change the dns entries on computers that have 2 nics. One has to change (lan1), the other doesnt.

I did have success changing the dns entries based on whether the nic card(s) had an ip address, however it added the dns entries on both nics not just the one.

When I try to isolate the one nic named lan1 it doesnt want to work for some reason. Can someone help me figure out what im  doing wrong?

Here is the first script which will change the dns on both nic cards:

```
$NICS = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $computer |where{$_.IPEnabled -eq "TRUE"}
    Foreach($NIC in $NICS){
$DNSServers = "8.8.8.8","4.4.4.4"
    $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNSServers)
    $NIC.SetDynamicDNSRegistration("TRUE")
}
write-host $Computer
```

Here is the Second version that im trying to get to work:

```
$NICS = Get-WMIObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration -computername $computer |where{$_.netconnectionID -eq "LAN1"}
    Foreach($NIC in $NICS){
$DNSServers = "8.8.8.8","4.4.4.4"
    $NIC.SetDNSServerSearchOrder($DNSServers)
    $NIC.SetDynamicDNSRegistration("TRUE")
}
write-host $Computer
```

Can anyone help me figure out why the "lan1" code isnt working?

Thanks

Comment: Are you doing this on the local computer or remote systems?

Comment: it is for remote computers within my lab network. I enter the computers FQDN in a text file so that it can grab the nic card info on each machine

Comment: I think I have the class wrong in the second part of the $NICS variable. How can I combine this statement to find only one ethernet adapter with netconnectionID = LAN1?

Comment: You can include filters in the `Get-WMIObject` command, I'd go with that.